# Possible memory leak on hadoop cluster ? (hive, hiveserver2, zeppelin, spark)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-nifi, apache-zeppelin

The heap usage of hiveserver2 is constantly increasing (first pic).
There are applications such as nifi, zeppelin, spark related to hive. Nifi use puthivesql, zeppelin use jdbc(hive) and spark use spark-sql. I couldn't find any clue to this.

[image]

Comment: What version of Zeppelin do you use?

Comment: 0.8.0.  I think it might have something to do with hive not zeppelin but more like nifi puthive component.

Answer (score 0):

Hive requires a lot of resources for establishing connection. So, first reason is a lot of queries in your puthiveql processor, cause for everyone of them hive need to open connection. Get attention on your hive job browser (you can use hue for this purpose)

Possible resolution: e.g. if you use insert queries - so use orc files to insert data. If you use update queries - use temporary table and merge query.